# In Haskell, is there a way to do IO in a function guard?

Tags: haskell, io, guard

For example:

```
newfile :: FilePath -> IO Bool
newfile x | length x <= 0 = return False
          | doesFileExist x == True = return False
          | otherwise = return True
```

Can this be made to work?

Comment: I believe that this is an edit of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138385 and not an independent question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works and does what's needed:

```
newfile :: FilePath -> IO Bool
newfile fn = do 
    x <- runErrorT $ do
        when ((length fn) <= 0) (throwError "Empty filename")
        dfe <- liftIO $ doesFileExist fn
        when (dfe) (throwError "File already exists")
        return True
    return $ either (\_ -> False) id x
```

Comment: `\\_ -> False` can be written `const False`.  Stylistically, I believe the latter carries the intent better, but it's effectively equivalent.

Answer (score 19):

You're already in the `IO` monad, so why not use the following?

```
newfile :: FilePath -> IO Bool
newfile x | length x <= 0 = return False
          | otherwise = do exists <- doesFileExist x
                           return $ not exists
```

For applicative goodness:

```
import Control.Applicative

newfile :: FilePath -> IO Bool
newfile x | length x <= 0 = return False
          | otherwise = not <$> doesFileExist x
```

As you can see, the applicative route is even more concise than the guards you'd like to use in your question!

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no way to do this (short of unsafe tricks which would be completely inappropriate here).

BTW `doesFileExist x == True` would be better written as `doesFileExist x` were it possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

The type of guard clauses must be `Bool`. The type of `doesFileExist x` is `IO Bool`. The type mismatch means you can't do that.

Comment: This doesn't really mean anything.  The type of `getLine` is `IO String`.  The type of `(++ "foo")` is `String -> String`.  But you can still feed `getLine` into `(++ "foo")` with the right combinators.  (Namely `(++ "foo") <$> getLine` instead of `(++ "foo") $ getLine`.  So the answer to this question is not as simple as your post may lead someone to believe.  (I think the word "No." would be more correct than your post, actually.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. I'm not sure how you expect to get a `Bool` out of an `IO Bool` using combinators. While you can use `unsafePerformIO` to get a `Bool` out of an `IO Bool`, please don't. Other than that, guard clauses require `Bool` expressions, and not an expression of any other type. So what did I miss? How is the single word "No" more correct, rather than an explanation of what is the expected type and what was the given type?

Comment: @jrockway yfeldblum is correct. The entire *point* of `IO` is that there is no way to turn an `IO a` into an `a`. Using the right combinators to apply `(++ "foo")` to `getLine` doesn't pull `getLine` out of `IO` to make it a `String` so that it fits the type of `(++ "foo")`, it puts `(++ "foo")` **into** `IO` to make it fit the type of `getLine`. There is no way to use `(++ "foo") <$> getLine` where you expected to be able to use a `String`, and this is by design. There is also no way to use a value of `IO Bool` where a `Bool` is needed.