# Haskell's liftIO's litter functions of type ErrorT String IO ()

Tags: haskell, io

I have a function that returns type `ErrorT String IO ()`. While the function works, `liftIO`'s litter every line that does IO. It makes for a mess. Is there any way to get around this and still have the ability to abort on error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume [this is the context of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138385/haskell-way-to-do-error-checking-of-multiple-items-with-abort/2141160#2141160), so I'll repost the comment I left over there in case you didn't notice it:

If you use a few particular functions a lot, you could write a wrapper around them, e.g. `liftedPutStr = liftIO . putStr`. You could even import the originals qualified and make your lifted version use the same name, if you wanted. Also, a group of IO actions that won't raise errors can be pulled out into a single, separate function that can then be `liftIO`d just once. Does that help?

In case you're not familiar with qualified imports, here's `putStr` again as an example:

```
import Prelude hiding (putStr)
import qualified Prelude as P
import Control.Monad.Trans

putStr x = liftIO $ P.putStr x
```

That should let you use the altered `putStr` in a transformed `IO` the same way you'd normally use the real `putStr` in plain `IO`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand I can define additional functions that hide the liftIO but I suppose there isn't a visually cleaner way to do this -- one way or another I must make the types fit.

Comment: Nothing else that I'm aware of. For keeping the important code visually cleaner, my suggestion would be to write a bunch of lifting wrappers in a separate module and import that. Still a bunch of junk code, but at least you don't have to look at it most of the time! I'm actually surprised a library doesn't already exist to lift the standard library `IO` actions into the `MonadIO` type class, but I just skimmed hackage and didn't see anything that seemed to do that.